# Inner join returning more rows then exist in tables

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Till today my thoughts about the inner join were it will return the minimum number of rows that exist in tables satisfying a joining condition.

**Ex.** if **table A** contains 4 rows and **table B** contains 7 rows . i was expecting that 4 rows can be the maximum output if they satisfy the joining condition.

I just wrote an sp in which i was creating two temporary tables and was populating them. then i took an inner join of them but returning more rows (In my case 29 rows were returned i was expecting 4)
After some search i found this 
 [link](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2012/02/09/sql-server-inner-join-returning-more-records-than-exists-in-table/)

which confirms that i can happen but i still wonder what are **my options** to limit the returned result.

Below is my stored procedure.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetDDFDetailOnSiteCol]
@siteId int,
@colNum int
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

create Table #portDetail
(
ddfId int,
portDetail nvarchar(50),
siteId int
)
Insert into #portDetail SELECT  ddf.id,  ddf.portDetail, site.Site_ID  from site
        inner join ddf ON site.Site_ID = ddf.siteCodeID 
        where ddf.siteCodeID = @siteId and ddf.colNo= @colNum
        order by colNo,blockNum,portRowNum,portColNum

create Table #portAllocationDetail
(
assigned_slot nvarchar(50),
siteId int
)
Insert into #portAllocationDetail 
SELECT  dbo.portList.assigned_slot, dbo.site.Site_ID
FROM dbo.portList INNER JOIN
 dbo.site ON dbo.portList.siteCodeID = dbo.site.Site_ID
 where dbo.site.Site_ID = @siteId

--select * from #portAllocationDetail   
Select #portDetail.ddfId,#portDetail.portDetail,#portAllocationDetail.siteId,#portAllocationDetail.assigned_slot FROM #portDetail 
INNER JOIN #portAllocationDetail 
ON
#portDetail.siteId = #portAllocationDetail.siteId
END
```

Comment: How do you determine which row(s) from Table B are returned?

Comment: i write select statements. one still exist commented

Answer (score 31, accepted):

An `inner join` repeats each matching row in TableB for each row in TableA.  So if there are 4 rows in TableA, and 7 in TableB, the maximum rowcount is 28.

[Example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/38706/1/0)

Comment: Then either TableA contains more than 4 rows or TableB contains more than 7 rows.

Comment: Hmm ok, How can i restrict it to four

Comment: @shah, we can;t answer your question becasue we have to know what data in the second table you want to kepp and what you don't want to keep. You don't want to randomly select a value from that table so we have to know what business rule you want us to show you how to apply.

Answer (score 1):

An inner join returns the subset of the cartesian product of the tables that satisfy the condition.
So for two tables A and B with rows n and m and a condition True, the join returns nxm rows and that is the maximum.

It is incredible how simple this explanation can be if only we used the correct terminology, but it takes me much more time to understand it "the simple way" which is how it is explained on most tutorials :(.

Answer (score -3):

Inner join results in duplicates too.

Use **intersect** operator if you want unique common values from both tables.

So, here intersect can even display null value if it is null on both sides.

Comment: if possible use the intersect operator in an example with the context of the question

Comment: select * from portDetail pd,portAllocationDetail pad where
pd.site_id = pad.site_id and
 pd.site_id in (select siteId from portDetail
intersect
select site_id from portAllocationDetail);

Answer (score -4):

----------inner join means- The INNER JOIN keyword returns rows when there is at least one match in both tables.-----------------